# Setting serialVersionUID for class based on activeProfiles in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, serialization, deserialization

I have a class which implements Serializable interface which basically acts as a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). Now this class is part of the *ind* branch, used as test Version of web application.

There is also another branch, *aus*, used as the production app. The production app is just legacy code, with fewer features.

As part of long term, we are trying to move to a single code base. So, basically the test version and production application will be using the code of the *ind* branch which seems to have the latest features. For that, we added multiple *application.properties* files apart from the default, setting active profiles using environment variables via [Jenkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29).

Now, both the *ind* branch code and *aus* branch code have this DTO class. In the *aus* code, it has a serialVersionUID manually specified. In the *ind* branch, it’s not manually specified, decided based on fields. Now, as part of moving the backend code of the *aus* branch to the *ind* branch code, the API call to return a list of objects, throws a serialization mismatch error, between the local class and stream class.

I want both the app to function separately as of now. So, when switching environments or active profiles using *speing.profiles.active*, serialVersionUID needs to switch like it was before when both the applications were separate. I have tried to get the current active profile via System.getProperty() and then check them, and setting serialVersionUID based on the profile.

Then, the [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot) application seems to show during startUp as the profile is set correctly, but when I try to set the activeProfile value in the class, it’s null.

I also tried adding a @Configuration file and obtain the active profile via @Value(). Everything works until application startUp, but it shows null when the API call to return the objects is performed.

```
@Configuration
public class ActiveProfileConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    String activeProfile;

     public boolean isInd() {
        System.out.println("active : "+activeProfile);
        return "in-test-local".equals(activeProfile);
    }

    public boolean isAus() {
        System.out.println("active : "+activeProfile);
        return "au-test-local".equals(activeProfile);
}
```

These are the latest changes made in order to obtain a dynamic serialVersionUID based on the current active profile.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ApiModel(value = "Organization", description = "Capture the information about the data of Organization")
public class Organization implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID;

    static {
        ActiveProfileConfiguration profileConfiguration = new ActiveProfileConfiguration();

        if(profileConfiguration.isInd()) {
            serialVersionUID = 74845715165655L;
            System.out.println("Ind");
        }
        else if(profileConfiguration.isAus()) {
            serialVersionUID = -8450977346456L;
            System.out.println("Aus");
        }
        else {
            serialVersionUID = 1L;
            System.out.println("else..");
        }
    }

String id;
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private Media logo;
    private Media advPic;
    private String website;
    @NotNull
    private String telephone;
    @NotNull
    private String businessCategoryId;
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private OrganizationPreferences preferences;
    private SuperAdminOrganizationControl superAdminControl;
    private Constants.OrganizationMode orgMode;
    @NonNull
    private String userSub;
    private String geoLocationId;
    private GeoLocation location;
    private String description;
    private String orgRef;
    private String orgUrl;
    private String orgEmail;
    private boolean superAdminEnable;
    @NotNull
    private String whatsAppNumber;
    private String privacyStatement;

    private Boolean isCallback;
    private String callbackId;
    //Only in response, not database
    private List<SelectOption> serviceCategoryList = new ArrayList<SelectOption>();

    List<ProviderServiceHours> workingHours = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

What am I missing here? Is there an alternate way for smooth functioning of same class in different environments?

Comment: The serialVersionUID is meant to be known at compilation time. Whereas Spring profiles are a runtime thing. You cannot and should not alter the serialVersionUID at runtime.

Comment: Oh Okay. So, How can I maintain the serialVersionUIDs of 2 different versions of apps to a single one code base , based on environment switch? Eg: In au-test , serialVersionUID = 1234567L;, in-test , serialVersionUID = 7891011 or some other values specified by compiler; , au-test. Now, That au-test is also gonna use ind branch. So, Does that mean , class irrespective of profile being set(ind.au-test), shall use manually specified branch..i.e., 1L ?? So, Can I remove the impact of currently active serialVersionUIDs, by re-initialising or re-assignment..

Comment: @OP You only get a problem if you try to run your old and new ‘ind’ code bases at the same time, i.e. one as client and one as server. Is this a realistic situation? Or if you have serializations of the old classes in a database, which you shouldn’t.

Comment: @GaëlJ Nonsense. It is either read or calculated at runtime. The compiler has no interest in it whatsoever. Nothing in the Object Serialization Specification supports your claim.

Comment: @user207421 The ind code base which tries to act as a single backend for both ind envt and aus envt. So, In this case, the ind code seems to run in 2 instances, one in the ind itself (original), and in aus (old aus code base changed to follow ind instead). All the envt selection is done by jenkins, setting envt variable. This envt variable passed onto spring.profiles.active in default config file, which in-turn determine the actual config file based on envt.

Comment: @user207421 So, In ind, application-ind.properties will run, In case of au, application-au.properties will run. Now, So, Basically same code base in 2 envts with diff configs accordingly. As both these are different apps deployed seperately, each of them has different Organizations stored in database. Trying to retrive them and converting to proper response object throws the error. Even though both app runs on different instances, what was expected is to retrieve the list of objects from database and obtain reponse. Hoped serialversionUID will also be maintained like it was before in old envt.

Comment: After all, Its accessing 2 different databases in 2 instances.

Comment: You still haven't clarified whether you are running the old and new 'ind' codebases in communication with each other, and if so why.

Comment: @user207421 The ind code base remains as it is , The ind envt runs using ind code base already. The au app's code base is switched to use ind code base. So, au app and ind app both remain seperated in user experience, backend code remains same. The ind code base contains multiple config files which differentiates the db, secrets etc to use based on envt chosen. And No we were not running old and new 'ind' code bases in communication with each other, as ind app, already uses ind branch and au-test branch is the one migrated. I hope we are on same page here ?

Comment: I find all this very confusing, but the fundamental question remains. Do you have to run both 'ind' codebases at the same time? If so, why? This is the source of your problem. If you can upgrade both ends at the same time, it disappears. You've certainly painted yourself into a massive problem here, but maybe some higher-level thinking can eliminate it.

Comment: @user207421 maybe my comment was not super clear. I didn't mean that the compiler needs it. I mean that it's supposed to represent the "definition"/"schema" of a class, thus something known at compile time and not altered at runtime. Technically you can alter it at runtime but unless very specific cases, it shouldn't be. I think OP's problem is actually more a deployment/architecture issue that should not be solved by serialVersionUID manipulations.

Comment: @GaëlJ I agree with your last sentence: but everything else you have stated here is incorrect. There is no way that either Java Serialization or any application code can detect whether a `final` constant was baked into the code or set during initialization. If you think otherwise please provide supporting evidence.

Answer (score 1):

After further investigation, I discovered that the problem was related to a cache issue on my end.

After switching the code base, the redis container was still on with old cache, so when the API to list the organizations showed mismatch. I flushed unwanted data and things are back good that both apps separately list the data correctly.

This was specific to my setup.